# C++ get stack-trace for specified thread

Tags: c++, windows, stack-trace

Problem is in function StackWalk64, function not working for other thread, only current thread.

From example: 
https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/478943-stackwalk64-and-x86/

```
    SymInitialize(process, symbolPath.c_str(), TRUE);

    displacement = 0;
    DWORD dwMachineType = IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64;
    stack.AddrPC.Offset = context.Rip;
    stack.AddrPC.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
    stack.AddrFrame.Offset = context.Rsp;
    stack.AddrFrame.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
    stack.AddrStack.Offset = context.Rsp;
    stack.AddrStack.Mode = AddrModeFlat;

    for (frame = 0; ; frame++)
    {
        result = StackWalk64
        (
            dwMachineType,
            process,
            mainThread,
            &stack,
            &context,
            NULL,
            SymFunctionTableAccess64,
            SymGetModuleBase64,
            NULL
        );

        symbol.SizeOfStruct = sizeof(IMAGEHLP_SYMBOL64);
        symbol.MaxNameLength = 255;


        SymGetSymFromAddr64(process, (ULONG64)stack.AddrPC.Offset, &displacement, &symbol);
        UnDecorateSymbolName(symbol.Name, (PSTR)name, 256, UNDNAME_COMPLETE);


        LogDebug << frame << " | " << String(symbol.Name);

        if (!result)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

I need print stack trace for main thread from other thread.

Comment: We can't see where `context` came from.  Probably not from mainThread.

Comment: Context is same function as this code.

Comment: I store context when start second thread, but context contain still equal stack trace.
I need print main stack trace from watchdog thread.